# HTTP 403 Forbidden in parallel when viewing symfony2 app

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to test an app in IE/Chrome/Firefox in windows via parallels but I get a HTTP 403 Forbidden. I use MAMP, and I have set up a virtual host on my mac and modified IP (host) in windows so I can test sites in IE. Every other app/site works except the one in Symfony2. Is there anything I need to do in Symfony2 to allow access to parallels? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to comment out the following lines in your `app_dev.php` :

```
// This check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to production servers.
// Feel free to remove this, extend it, or make something more sophisticated.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1'))
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
```

Im assuming your attempting to access your `dev` environment ? By Default it doesn't allow connection from a host other than `127.0.0.1`

**Note:** these lines should be uncommented or the file not placed on a production server - as it will allow access to your dev environment remotely

Comment: @jmdesigner81 please make sure you accept answers to all of the questions you ask on StackOverflow - you accept and answer by clicking the tick next to an answer